# Cannot find file path - image

Tags: c#, android, ftp, xamarin, android-resources

I am currently trying to send an image over FTP on Android.
I tried a lot of possible ways to accomplish that, and the same problem persists: I get an error telling that the path/directory/file doesn't exist.

My code right now is using the CameraSample from Xamarin and getting the picture taken from the camera and trying to send it over FTP. When I try to do that, I receive the error:

> ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // make it available in the gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(_file);
        System.Console.WriteLine (contentUri.ToString ());
        mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
        SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        // display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display
        // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory 
        // and cause the application to crash.
        int height = _imageView.Height;
        int width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = _file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height))
        {
            _imageView.RecycleBitmap ();
            _imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        Thread t = new Thread ( () => UploadToFTP(contentUri.ToString()));
        t.Start ();
    }

    private void UploadToFTP(String uri){
        SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP ();
        ftp.Connect("xxx.xxxxx.xxx", 21, "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
        ftp.Stor (new File(uri));
        ftp.Disconnect();
    }
```

Does anyone have an ideia what is happening? I've tried with assets/drawable/files etc. and nothing works. *The image can be seen on the ImageView.*

The path printed on the console is this one:

> file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/CameraAppDemo/myPhoto_64ee3fec-08af-4bde-9214-62892b6d9f72.jpg

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I figured it out... The problem is the use of `contentUri.ToString()` instead of `contentUri.Path`, this latter the result is the correct and without the *"file://"* part, so it should be something like that:

> /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/CameraAppDemo/myPhoto_64ee3fec-08af-4bde-9214-62892b6d9f72.jpg

Comment: Did you verified that the file exists? Did you precluded that Guid.NewGuid() is called multiple times?

Comment: You should check the file is physically exists first: `if (_file.exists()) Log.d(TAG, "file exists");`

Comment: Yep, the file should exist because it's displayed on the imageView correctly!